# RequireJS and dependencies of 3rd party libraries eg. Backbone dependent on Underscore and jQuery

Tags: requirejs

I understand that Backbone is dependent on Underscore, jQuery and maybe JSON2. So is it possible to specify that so when I say my module is dependent on Backbone, it will include dependencies of that? Or whats they way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RequireJS makes this easy with the dependencies that you can declare when `define` a module. For libraries that don't support AMD (Underscore and Backbone being two primary examples) then use of the `shim` configuration is required.

Here is an example config:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'scripts/',
    paths: {
        'backbone': 'lib/backbone',
        'jquery': 'lib/jquery',
        'underscore': 'lib/underscore'
    },
    shim: {
        'backbone': {
            deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        }
    }
});
```

Now if you require Backbone as a dependency in one of your modules `underscore` and `jquery` will be available.

A lot of this [is also covered in the documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, and many people have had issues with this as well. The shim seems to not enforce anything. Any ideas/cases where it wouldn't?

Comment: Are you referring specifically to Backbone/Underscore?

Comment: Yes, I keep getting Backbone is not defined, but not every time as it seems to be however long it takes to load certain dependencies in time. Compiling with node fixed the issue, but it should work without doing that.